# eloquent model laravel get one to many inside loop

Tags: laravel, model

i have laravel project .. 
and i have to get users 
this is my

```
        <table class='table table-responsive table-hover table-responsive  draggable'  border='5'>
        <thead>
            <tr class='warning'>
                <input id='searchAjaxText' type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='رقم الهاتف أو اسم المستخدم أو الايميل'/>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id='searchAjaxResult'>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

and this is my js as key up

```
$("#searchAjaxText").keyup(function(){
var searchAjaxText = $(this).val();
if(searchAjaxText != '')
{
    $.get
    (
        "/users/search/"+searchAjaxText+"",
        {
            searchAjaxText:searchAjaxText
        },
        function(data)
        {
            $("#searchAjaxResult").html(data)
            console.log(data);
        }
    )
  }
})
```

and this is my Route code

```
Route::get("/users/search/{keyword}",'UsersController@searchScoop');
```

and this is my controller code

```
public function searchScoop($keyword)
{
    $user = User::searchScoop($keyword);
    return $user;
}
```

and this is my searchoop function inside the model

```
public static function searchScoop($keyword)
{
    $users = User::where('username','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->
    orwhere('email','like','%'.$keyword.'%')->
    orwhere('phone','like','%'.$keyword.'%')
    ->get(['id','username','phone','division','permission']);
    return $users;
}
```

now i get this on my console

```
Array[1]
 0
:
Object
division : 3
id : 15
permission : 3
phone :"0788511619"
username : "bashar"
```

now the permission and the division is numbers .. 
how can i get the permission name from the Permission model and the division name fro mthe Division model by the id i gat it from users table ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load permissions for each user by using [`with()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) method:

```
$users = User::where('username', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
             ->orwhere('email', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
             ->orwhere('phone', 'like', '%'.$keyword.'%')
             ->with('permissions', 'divisions')
             ->get(['id', 'username', 'phone', 'division', 'permission']);
```

[One to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many) relationship should be defined like this:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Permission', 'permission', 'id');
}
```